# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/… Reason: image not found when code signed

Tags: macos, dylib, codesign

I have an app bundle containing a cli tool and a dylib. For testing I am calling the cli tool in Terminal (iTerm2):

**DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./libwebsockets.14.dylib THNUCLNT_SVC="private" ./thnuclnt -v**

**dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libwebsockets.14.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/rwelz/Downloads/ezeep Connector.app/Contents/Resources/thnuclnt/thnuclnt/x86_64-darwin/./thnuclnt
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6**

When I remove the signature from cli tool, everything works fine:

**codesign --remove-signature thnuclnt**

**DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./libwebsockets.14.dylib THNUCLNT_SVC="private" ./thnuclnt -v**

**ThinPrint Client Mac Version 7.6.10.1, (c) 2007-2019 ThinPrint GmbH**

removing signature from libwebsockets.14.dylib has no effect at all.

I know that the cli tool is using dlopen to load the dylib. But I have no code for the cli tool nor for the libwebsockets.dylib since these are programmed by a colleague of mine. I am only responsible for putting everything together in the app bundle. But everything is build on our build server - so everything uses the same certificate for code signing.

I expect my cli tool to load libwebsockets.dylib and execute and output the same as if it had no signature.

What is changing on the cli tool when codesign is applied? What is going on here?

Many thanks for your valuable help

regards,

Robert

PS.:

libwebsockets.14.dylib and tnuclnt reside in the same directory inside the resource folder of the app:

~/Downloads/my_supersecret.app/Contents/Resources/thnuclnt/thnuclnt/x86_64-darwin/] $ ls -l

total 3368

-rwxr-xr-x  1 rwelz  staff   268K Sep 25 11:35 libwebsockets.14.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x  1 rwelz  staff   321K Sep 25 11:35 thnuclnt

Comment: What was `rpath` set to when `thnuclnt` was built?

Comment: How do I get this information? thnuclnt is no Xcode project (no Xcode-build call)

otool -L thnuclnt says:
 ...
 @rpath/libwebsockets.14.dylib (compatibility version 14.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
 ...

Comment: Before signing we applied

install_name_tool -change @rpath/libwebsockets.14.dylib @executable_path/libwebsockets.14.dylib thnuclnt

and the error is gone. Now we get a new one:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
 Referenced from: /Users/bsvc/Codeshare/test/x86_64-darwin/./thnuclnt
 Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

What is the install_name_tool call to bend 

/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib

to

/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib

?

Comment: The `rpath` is set during linking and is normally something like `../Frameworks` when building a macOS app bundle.  It's a way of setting the location of all the `dylib`s in a more abstract way.  The other error you talk about means libssl is a third-party library which will also need bundling as users wont have it installed in their system.  You will have to do a similar job with `install_name_tool` on that too.

Comment: install_name_tool -change /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib thnuclnt
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib thnuclnt

did the trick. Thanks for your input. Regards, Robert

Comment: Does someone know, why changing the @rpath is neccessary for signed cli tool and dylibs and not for unsigned ones? Whats the difference in Gatekeeper's behaviour between signed and unsigned binaries?

Comment: Hmm, that looks way off.  If those libraries are from `/usr/local` they need to copied into the app bundle as they won't exist on the end-user system.  If they are standard and live in `/usr/lib` then why are you linking in from `/usr/local/`?

Comment: That tool is build not under my control (on a build server). I am not able to change anything there.